# hibernate native sql query returned

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to do a native SQL query, which joins 2 Tables.

The return value should be all elements of the District Table, which would be `(id, name, district_code, coordinates)`, and also a `count(*)` of all Objects which are in a `District` (therefore the join with some other table).

So I have all columns of district `(district.*)` one field which is `Count(*)`.
Which kind of query can I use, so that I can comfortable use it in my java code? I can't add an entity or, because the `count(*)` wouldn't fit to it!?

I have got a District class which looks like this:

```java
@XmlRootElement
public class District extends AbstractEntity{

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int district_code;
    @Transient
    private int carsQuantity;

    public District(){}

    @Override
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;       
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getDistrict_code() {
        return district_code;
    }

    public void setDistrict_code(int district_code) {
        this.district_code = district_code;
    }

    public int getCarsQuantity() {
        return carsQuantity;
    }

    public void setCarsQuantity(int carsQuantity) {
        this.carsQuantity = carsQuantity;
    }
}
```

My District.hbm.xml:

```java
<hibernate-mapping package="at.opendata.entitys">      
    <class name="District" table="districts">       
        <id name="id" column="id">
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>
        <property name="name"/>
        <property name="district_code"/>                
    </class>    
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**EDIT:**

I can't do it with HQL oder JPQL, because I need a SUBSELECT in my FROM CLAUSE.

```sql
SELECT d.id, count(*) FROM (SELECT cd.coordinates AS coordinates FROM cars AS c LEFT JOIN cardetail AS cd ON (c.car_id = cd.car_id)) AS c CROSS JOIN districts AS d WHERE ST_CONTAINS(d.coordinates, c.coordinates) GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't need a native query for that. JPQL will do just fine. And the result of such a query will simply be a `List<Object[]>`, where each object array will contain an element for each returned column. Just iterate over this list and do whatever you want with the elements:

```
for (Object[] row : list) {
    Integer id = (Integer) row[0];
    String name = (String) row[1];
    ...
    Long count = (Long) row[4];
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i need an native SQL Query, because i cant do an inner select in my FROM clause.
Please see yourself:
SELECT d.id, name, district_code, count(*) 
FROM (SELECT cd.coordinates AS coordinates FROM cars AS c LEFT JOIN cardetail AS cd ON (c.car_id = cd.car_id)) AS c 
CROSS JOIN districts AS d 
WHERE ST_CONTAINS(d.coordinates, c.coordinates) 
GROUP BY id

Comment: That doesn't change anything. The SQL query would still return a List<Object[]>, where the first element of each row would be the ID, the second one would be the name, etc.